# Abode XD : Simple Template converting to html code

Tags: html, css

I have built an email confirmation template. I want to convert it to html to use it on email confirmations.
I have 0 experience with converting templates to code, what should I use to convert the code or what should I know before doing it?
Here's the link to my template.
https://xd.adobe.com/spec/0a1e7aeb-a0af-4471-5d49-9659faf04c44-7c2f/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML / CSS from Adobe XD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532212/convert-html-css-from-adobe-xd)

Answer (score -1):

You need to know basics of HTML and CSS generally to conconvert templates to code .

**now for your template you need to know from HTML :**

1. heading tag
2. image tag
3. paragraph tag
4. div tag : to division your page to boxes which contain your content,your design have a main box which include heading, image and other paragraphs, this box divided to box contain the image and another one which contain the text below it.

**You need to know from CSS :**

5. how to change background color
6. how to change your text color
7. margin and padding to set spaces for your design
8. height and width to set your boxes height and width
9. font-family to change your font style
10. border-radius to define the radius of the element's corners.

you can use "https://www.w3schools.com/" as a reference to learn those things.

hope this useful for you.